# replace Group2 in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have below text

```
    ABCDEF
     JHJHJNJN<098978686
     <jjg>
    HGHJFGV XXXX    
       10-10-2018
    JHKGHKGHG
        JKHJHHJM
10-10-2019 JGHHGHGVH
HBVJHBHBB
```

I want to replace date followed by XXX+number of spaces
Here is my code

```
public class Regexreplace {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String inp = "    ABCDEF"
                     +" JHJHJNJN<098978686"
                     +"     <jjg>         "
                     +" HGHJFGV XXXX     "
                     +"     10-10-2018  "
                     +" JHKGHKGHG  "
                     +"     JKHJHHJM"
                     +"     10-10-2019 JGHHGHGVH"
                     +" HBVJHBHB    ";
        String ipRegex = "(XXXX.*)[\\s]+([\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{4})";

        System.out.println(inp.replaceAll(ipRegex, "$110-11-2018"));

    }

}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEF  JHJHJNJN<098978686      <jjg>           HGHJFGV XXXX            10-10-2018      JHKGHKGHG       JKHJHHJM    10-11-2018 JGHHGHGVH    HBVJHBHB
```

Why its replacing the second date in text ?

Comment: Because you have a greedy match anything sequence in your regex, after `XXXX`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, but if am removing greedy, then spaces are not coming after XXXX  in output..!

Comment: Add the spaces to your capturing group: `(XXXX\\s+)`; or just make the match anything sequence non-greedy: `.*?`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, Its working Thanks. But can you please little explain more why mine is not working ?

Comment: I wrote up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's replacing the second date because you have a greedy "match anything" sequence in your regular expression:

```
"(XXXX.*)[\\s]+([\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{4})"
//    ^^
//   Here
```

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) explain the difference between greedy and non-greedy (lazy) quantifiers. In a nutshell:

> The standard quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy, meaning
>   they match as much as they can, only giving back as necessary to match
>   the remainder of the regex.

For your input, this means that the `.*` sequence will match everything up to the line that contains the second date.

Since you don't have a need to "match anything", one solution would be to remove the greedy sequence altogether, and bring the whitespace matching sequence inside your capturing group:

```
"(XXXX\\s+)(\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4})"
```

<sub>**Note:** there's no need to put `\\d` or `\\s` inside a character class (`[\\s]`).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try with this reg expression

```
"XXXX[\\s]+([\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{1,2}-[\\d]{4})"
```

Answer (score 0):

`((XXXX\s*)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$)`this will match all dd-mm-yyyy format date followed by XXXX.....